# If series $\sum_n^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges, then does $\sum_n^{\infty} {a_n}^2$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If series $\sum_n^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges, then does $\sum_n^{\infty} {a_n}^2$ converge? If not give a counterexample.

This is true only when ${a_n}^2 ≤ \frac{|a_n|}{n}$ but I can't think of a counterexample

Comment: Try to think of a simple sequence $a_n$ that satisfies the hypothesis.

Comment: Your sentence "This is true only when ..." is totally false, so make sure you understand why you're wrong.

Comment: You may also note that the converse of above statement is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Counterexample: $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

This is from the following: $$\sum_n^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$$ This converges when $p>1$, but diverges when $p=1$.

Comment: I was going to go with $a_n = (-1)^n$, but this works too.

Comment: I like this example better (and this is the one I was thinking of) because it shows that even absolute convergence isn't enough to force the result.  In general, the $p$-series is an excellent starting point for trying to find counterexamples for this sort of result - if a conjecture is true for all the $p$-series then it may be worth trying to find a proof,